# how to verify what im typing is not storaged in database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

How can I know if what I am typing in my input="text" , is not storaged in my database without using ajax.
just PHP , LARAVEL  or JS ?.
Example:
Database
id | code | description ...

in my Form:
Insert Code :
<input="text">
while I am typing the code and if it  is similar with any insert in database I need to show a error saying "Code already Storaged"

Comment: Without using `ajax` this seems fairly pointless and inefficient. You'd use something similar to `autotype`, but instead of giving you positive outcomes it'd express that there is an existing 'string'. However, you should just put a `unique` key on the column in the database you don't want duplicates in...........

Comment: What is approximation of maximal amount (rows) table will have?